# Can java use openAL renderer?

Tags: java, openal

Is there a way to use the openal renderer with java? I have heard that the OpenAL.dll (dynamic linked library) is from c++. So how would you go about doing that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. The wrapper library, JOAL, allows you to access OpenAL. Specifically, this allows Java programmers to use 3D sound in applications. You can find support for JOAL, as well as JOGL and JOCL, at http://jogamp.org/. The [JOAL](http://jogamp.org/joal/www/) website contains links to OpenAL specifications and guides, as well as JOAL-specific tutorials and demoes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That's good because at some point I will want to make a 3d game and I don't want to have to download java3d.

Comment: Yeah I made a new account a couple of days ago.

Comment: Can I give you a piece of advice? When an answer, well, answers your question, you can accept it by clicking on the little check next to the points in an answer. This gives points to the answer-er, and people who accept answers are more likely to get their questions answered in the future :)